# How to use Magento HTTP\Client\Curl with HTTPS Url

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How can I do a curl get request if the URL is in SSL? I get an error of malform url or 419. But I used a valid url. I'm thinking is probably the URL is in HTTPS? Although I'm not sure. So I was thinking of adding a header parameter in the client/curl in magento. But I have no idea on how to achieve this. Right now I only have this

```
try{
        $this->_curl->get($file, []);
        $this->_curl->setOption(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = $this->_curl->getBody();
        // $this->_logger->debug($response, []);
        return $response;

    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        $this->_logger->critical('Error Curl', ['exception' => $e]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS will work well with Magento Curl.

For example, you can add a Json content type header

```
$this->_curl->addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```